# Two inner nested loop run time

Tags: java, runtime

```
void smiley (int n) { 

 for (int i = 0; i < n * n; ++i) { 
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
      System.out.println(”k = ” + k); 
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) 
      System.out.println(”j = ” + j); 
   } 
}
```

As you can see, there are two inner loops and one outer loop. The run time for this is `n^4`. I get `n * n` makes it `n^2`, but how does the two inner loops make the total run time `n^4`?

PS

One similar case here, its run time is `n^2`. I also don't get it. It has three loops right?

```
void smiley (int n, int sum) { 
 for (int i = 0; i < n * 100; ++i) { 
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) 
       sum++; 
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
       sum++; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is O(n^4)?

Comment: look at the bounds more carefully, the first one runs N^2 times while the second one runs n*100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run time isn't a function of the number of loop constructs, but of the number of times the code loops.  So if a loop is executed 100 times and it contains an inner loop executed 100 times, then the inner loop is executed 10,000 times.

For the 1st case, the outer loop is O(n^2), the 1st inner loop is O(n^2 * n^2), the 2nd inner loop is O(n^2 * n), so the total order is O(n^2 + n^4 + n^3), reduced to O(n^4).

For the 2nd case, the outer loop is O(n), the 1st inner loop is O(n * n), the 2nd inner loop is O(n * n), so the total order is O(n + n^2 + n^2), reduced to O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the first inner loop is limited by `i` which itself is limited by `n^2`. I suspect this might be the `n^4` you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is N(N + N) = 2N^2.  So that code is on the order of 2N^2.  Three nested loops would give N^3 run time N(N(N)).

Comment: How does the first one has a run time of n^4?

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you're iterating for `(int i = 0; i < n * n; ++i)`, so basically `n^2`, that's all right - you knew it. Inside that loop, you're iterating for `(int k = 0; k < i; ++k)`... ultimately, `i` here will go up to `n*n` (`n^2`). So your algorithm complexity is already about `O(n^4)`:

```
overall complexity =
    outer loop complexity: n^2
    *
    (
        1st inner loop complexity: up to n^2
        +
        2nd inner loop complexity: n
    )
```

You don't care so much about the second inner loop here, since it just adds a "small" number of operations compared to those added by the first loop (`n^2 + n` stills roughly equals `n^2`, from an algorithmic complexity point of view).

---

About your second piece of code:

```
overall complexity =
    outer loop complexity: n
    *
    (
        1st inner loop complexity: n
        +
        2nd inner loop complexity: up to n
    )
```

Which is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void smiley (int n) { 

 for (int i = 0; i < n * n; ++i) { 
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
      System.out.println(”k = ” + k); 
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) 
      System.out.println(”j = ” + j); 
   } 
}
```

for i we will get 0~n^2 and for every value i, we also get k loop from 0 to i, and j from n to 0
that we will get

```
∑_(i=0)^(n^2)* (∑_(j=0)^(i^2)+ ∑_(k=0)^n)  ≅ ∑_(i=0)^(n^2)* (∑_(j=0)^(i^2))  ≅∑_(i=0)^(n^2)* (∑_(j=0)^(n^2))  ≅ n^4
```

for this one:

```
void smiley (int n, int sum) { 
 for (int i = 0; i < n * 100; ++i) { 
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) 
       sum++; 
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) 
       sum++; 
    } 
}
```

we will get  n * (n + n) = 2*n^2 ~=n^2，that is mean we just caluate： loop in loop we use multiplication; loop alongside loop we use add; ignore the constant part.

maybe you can look here： http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the loops like this:

```
void smiley (int n) { 

 for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) { 
    for (int k = i+1; k < n*n; k++); 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++); 
   } 
}
```

Outer loop runs Nˆ2 times. For each cycle of outer loop the first inner loop runs Nˆ2-i. i=0, k loops Nˆ2-0; i=1, k loops Nˆ2-1; … ; i=Nˆ2-1, k loops 0 times.

So the time spent is *Nˆ2-0 + Nˆ2-1 + … + 0=Nˆ2*(0 + Nˆ2)/2=Nˆ4/2*

Second inner loop is simpler: j doesn't depend on i. i loops Nˆ2 times and j loops N times for every i loop.

Time spent for second inner loop is *Nˆ2 * N = Nˆ3*

The running time, as a function of the input size would be *T(N) = Nˆ4/2 + Nˆ3*

But asymptotic time would be Nˆ4, removing any constants and low power variables.